# How to split the total rows inside a data frame into equal buckets into another dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with 10333 records

```
df.shape[0]
10333
```

I want to split the records equally and write into four other dataframe equally. How can this done.

```
 df1.shape[0] =2853
 df2.shape[0] =2853
 df3.shape[0] =2853
 df4.shape[0] =2854
```

How can this be done.I am looking for solutions were records split equally based on the number of buckets mentioned.

Comment: `df1 = df.iloc[0:2853]` ...

Comment: @QuangHoang,I want  to dynamically that is based on the number of bucket mentioned.

Comment: Do you want to slice them continuously or alternatively? Ben's answer allows for the former.

Comment: @QuangHoang, Also I would not knowing the number of records inside the original dataframe and I am looking for solution which automatically counts the records and splits equally based on the number of buckets mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for `tile`:

```
ll = len(df)
groups = np.tile(np.arange(4), ll)[:ll]

dfs = {k:v for k,v in df.groupby(groups)}

len(dfs), len(dfs[0])
# (4, 2584)
# so the lengths of dataframes are 2854, 2853, 2853, 2853
```

Comment: @ I am trying to understand your code. How would I then assign splitted records to the dataframes `df1,df2,df3,df4`.That has to be done manully right?

Comment: Yes, but you can also access them as `dfs[0], dfs[1], dfs[2], dfs[3]`

Comment: It would be nice to see, if we create dynamically the dataframes `df1,df2,df3,df4,.`. based on the bucket mentioned and then assign the values